# uploading images to mysql second table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php form that submits data to one table and then images to a second table in my mysql database.

The bit i am stuck on is submitting to the second table for what ever reason it just doesnt seam to be working.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to where i am going wrong with this code?

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

```
<?php
/*
Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password)
*/
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['title']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']);
$sqm = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sqm']);
$sqm_land = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sqm_land']);
$type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['type']);
$area = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['area']);
$location = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['location']);
$bedroom = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['bedroom']);
$terrace = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['terrace']);
$orientation = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['orientation']);
$water = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['water']);
$seaview = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['seaview']);
$pool = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pool']);
$ownerinfo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['ownerinfo']);
$gaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gaddress']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['description']);
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['image']);
$lastid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastid']);
$seq = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['seq']);



// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO property (title, price, sqm, sqm_land, type, area, location, bedroom, terrace, orientation, water, seaview, pool, ownerinfo, gaddress, description) VALUES 
('$title', '$price', '$sqm', '$sqm_land', '$type', '$area', '$location', '$bedroom', '$terrace', '$orientation', '$water', '$seaview', '$pool', '$ownerinfo', '$gaddress', '$description' )";

function insertimages($image,$lastid,$seq){
        $query="insert into images(imagepath,property_id,imageorder) values('".$image."','".$lastid."','".$seq."')";
        $this->execQuery($query);
    }
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}




// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Where are you calling function insertimages() ??

Comment: function insertimages($image,$lastid,$seq){
        $query="insert into images(imagepath,property_id,imageorder) values('".$image."','".$lastid."','".$seq."')";
        $this->execQuery($query);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have declared the insertimages function but not calling. You can call like this:

```
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    insertimages($image,$lastid,$seq);
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```